# Getting the recent images from gallery from cursor using ContentResolver

Tags: android, cursor, image-gallery, android-contentresolver

I'm using `Cursor` to get the images from gallery and getting all the images from gallery, is there any way to get only few recent images, such as last 20 image captured.

One more problem, I am facing is the images are coming from older to new order, I want to get the image in reverse order(new to older).

```
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
```

My code to get image:

```
public void getImg(){
    Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
            null, orderBy);

    int image_column_index = imagecursor
            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }
    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    imagecursor.close();
}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setId(position);
        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int id = cb.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });

        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
        holder.id = position;
        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    int id;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/amirarcane/recent-images

Comment: Thanks man I'll check this :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order by argument to [query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String%29), per documentation, is formatted as a SQL order by statement.  If you want the values in descending order as opposed to the default ascending order, do this:

```
final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
```

But you specifically asked about using the date as the ordering, so you probably want this instead:

```
final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
```

Comment: Thanks man can you give a solution to get only 20 recent captured images from the cursor, as my main problem is to get only few images, when i have a lot of images in gallery the app go slow sometines,I guess requesting for only fiew images will prevent the latency

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640480/specifying-limit-offset-for-contentprovider-queries

Comment: I tryed to use it, but if i will use that i have to remove orderBy and my app is crashing to use it any better solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Doug's answer, if you only want the 20 most recent with the orderBy, you can do that:

`final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC LIMIT 20";`